# Assign a row in a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional numpy ndarray and I want to set the first row as a certain list/array of values however I cannot figure out the assignment. My code as follows:

```
matrix = numpy.ndarray(shape=(3, 5), dtype=str)
matrix[0] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
print(matrix[0])
>>> ['' '' '' '' '']
```

I wish to use an ndarray as it fits in nicely with my other code I am working on. I can't seem to find an easy way to just assign the row as this set of values.

Comment: Use an appropriate dtype there that would accomodate single char strings : `numpy.ndarray(shape=(3, 5), dtype='S1')`.

Comment: Or `object` dtype to have more flexibility : `dtype=object)`.

Comment: @Divakar That worked! Thanks very much! I must have missed that detail when reading the docs.